# Is there a fast way to get to the bottom of the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In Tiny Death Star, you can get to the top of your tower by tapping on the top of the screen while avoiding the "Add Level" button. However, the only way I can find to go to the bottom of the tower is to wait for someone to want an elevator ride, and tap on the button to give them that ride. Is there any other hot-spot for getting to the bottom of your Death Star?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, no.  I wish there were.  At least one does not exist on the iOS version.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I just keep my Mos Espa Cafe on the 2nd floor vacant. It just doesn't make enough money to be worth staffing. So I have a permanent "!" button which takes me to the lowest non-stocked floor - which will always be Level 2.

Comment: My only problem with this method is that it takes away the function of the ! Button for finding the other levels that need attention.

Comment: RE: Dang Khoa, That's why I've been using all of my upgrading bitizens on "The Catina & Mos Espa Cafe" I mean sure the stock only goes up a bit, but once you have the upgrade rank at 10 it defiantly pays off. Your method is tempting but I'm already rank 7 on both these levels and I quite like fast stocking as I play the game for hours on end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hold down one finger while tapping another in the direction you want to travel. The screen will move the distance between your fingers, as fast as you can tap. Alternatively, you can tap and hold one finger, tap and hold another finger, release the first, then release the second finger. If done rapidly, the game will scroll the full distance in the direction from first to second tap - all the way up or all the way down.

Comment: I'm not able to repeat your instructions. I'm on an android, and i think it's the latest version as of this comment, but i can't replicate your results.